# Populate visitors IP address in the controller for Geocoder near() query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I want to grab the visitors IP address and use it in my controller so that I can use geocoder to find nearby objects.

So I have a Location model, and I want to run a query like this:

```
def index
  @json = Location.near('visitor location here', 20).to_gmaps4rails
end
```

So I can show them a map pre-populated with the closest locations.

How do I access their IP address and use it in the controller? Can it be done? Should I be trying to accomplish this in the model using a scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your controller:

```
request.remote_ip
```

Comment: Thanks!

If anyone else gets stuck here, this is what I changed from the above example:

    def index
      @json = Location.near(request.remote_ip,20).to_gmaps4rails
    end